# How to plot black lines in geom_density2d for 2 categories?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Here is the code

```
dfr<-rbind(data.frame(hd=rnorm(100, 0.05, 0.1), bit.cnt=rnorm(100, 5000, 2000), type="a"),
      data.frame(hd=rnorm(300, 0.45, 0.1), bit.cnt=rnorm(300, 3000, 2000), type="b")
      )
ggplot(data=dfr, aes(x=hd, y=bit.cnt, colour=type)) + geom_point(alpha=0.5) + geom_density2d()
```

It produces blue and red density lines. Is it possible to make those lines black, while keeping colors of points?

Comment: I updated my example and added the `group` parameter to the original `aes()` definition.

Comment: Thanks! Where could I find documentation about group? It is not mentioned in manuals for aes, or geom_density2d, or stat_density2d, or kde2d.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define the `group=type` and then set the color to 'black' within the `geom_density2d`.

```
ggplot(data=dfr, aes(x=hd, y=bit.cnt, colour=type, group=type)) + 
    geom_point(alpha=0.5) + geom_density2d(color='black')
```

Comment: forgot the `group` aesthetics within the ggplot command. Should work now.